# How should I design this, not sure if it's a container or card

Tags: design, interface, cards, design-system

I'm currently in charge of the design system and we have this component which I'm not sure if I can consider it a card, or should I just use the general term 'container'. I tried googling and results for cards mostly describe them as short pieces of information that you can click into to learn more, and usually includes an image or visual. As for results for container, it's very varied but the general idea is that container is a broad term encompassing card + other components that are not consistent across.

Attached is an image of my design, as you can see, it consist of large pieces of information. This is a previous design done by someone else, the idea is that they don't want the information to look like it's 'floating' if without the container (Irony though, because by putting it in the container and giving it shadow makes it look like it IS floating). That aside, please don't question me about the current design. My problem is, I can't find best practices online because I don't know what terms to use. And I need to figure out the measurements of such 'cards'/'containers' when we use it, as well as for the other types (included in more images below). For example, when should we use it, how should each element be placed, how big can it be etc. The typical design system stuff.

[image: Card/container 1]

Any comments are welcomed, thank you in advance :)

Another:
[image: card/container 2]

Another:
[image: card/container 3]

Answer (score 2):

**Container** is a very broad term, mostly used in programming to wrap all content.

**Card** in UI usually consists of image, text and buttons, which implies interactivity.

The term used for information blocks, regardless of their content and functionality, whether they have interactivity or not, is information box:  **Info Box**.

Comment: Hi Danielillo, thank you so much for your comment. It really helps point me in another right direction :') I did a quick google search on info box, although it seems like not many use this term, but I did find what I wanted to look for! Thank you again, have a nice day!